# Yoast breadcrumbs not displaying correctly on imported WooCommerce products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, import, yoast

I am importing products via [Product Import Export for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/) by [WebToffee](https://www.webtoffee.com/), I then have a function that pulls data from an API and populates the data in each imported product.

Everything works perfectly, except Yoast breadcrumbs don't show properly when I view the product. The breadcrumbs on the frontend will say e.g.
`Shop » Product Name` instead of the full category and sub-category breadcrumb trail.

The only way I can successfully get the breadcrumbs to show properly is by manually editing the product and clicking update, it then shows correctly, as in:

```
Shop » Workwear » High Visibility » Hi Vis Polo Shirts & T-Shirts » Product Name
```

This would be fine, except I will be importing thousands of products in one sitting so I need a programmatic solution to add to my function which will make the breadcrumbs display properly on the frontend.

**What I've tried so far**

In my function I've tried populating the following custom metadata within each product:

```
_yoast_wpseo_metadesc
_yoast_wpseo_title
_yoast_wpseo_primary_product_cat
_yoast_wpseo_content_score
_yoast_wpseo_estimated-reading-time-minutes
```

But unfortunately setting all of the above doesn't seem to affect the display of the breadcrumbs.

I've also tried clearing product transients in wp-admin after import and product creation but this didn't resolve the issue.

Any ideas on how I can get this working? Is there a function I can run as part of the WC-Product object which will trigger the breadcrumbs to sort themselves out as it does when manually clicking Update in edit product?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it really depends how you're importing products. Currently, when each product insert, SEO Yoast meta isn't setting up in database so everytime you need to edit and update that product.

The custom meta might also not worked in your case because you're not inserting data in other Yoast table like `_yoast_indexable`.

Can you show us how you're importing products so we might help you?

Comment: I'm using the following plugin (https://www.webtoffee.com/product/product-import-export-woocommerce/) for importing a CSV file of just three columns - SKU, Title, tax:product-type.

I then hook into the plugin's custom hook: "wt_woocommerce_product_import_inserted_product_object" to carry out the API requests and programmatically set the title, slug, description, product category, product brand, yoast meta title & description, images etc

Comment: $product->save(); is called multiple times within my function, but this doesn't appear to trigger the same yoast backend functions (namely to sort the breadcrumbs) that are called when update is manually clicked in edit product

Comment: Did you try any other plugin? I mostly create my own importer but I'm not sure if that helps you to setup Yoast Meta, you can test that by inserting post/product using this function `wp_insert_post( $args );`

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me Alex, I'll be honest I'm a bit too far in deep with using this particular plugin as part of the solution to try another route now. I did contact Yoast directly and they mentioned downloading Yoast Test Helper plugin and going to Tools > Yoast Test > Reset indexables & migrations (I guess I can do this once all products have been imported and listed), so it sounds like you were on the right track with your answer regarding the _yoast_indexable table, I'll mark yours as an accepted answer based on that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps anyone else in the future having the same issue, the problem was due to my code, which modified the category and Yoast primary category after the last execution of wp_update_post.

Simply running wp_update_post( $product_id ) after programmatically updating the category / primary category fixed the malformed breadcrumb issue.